# Railsでリクエストごとのタイムスタンプを取得する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

リクエストを受けるごとに、その時点の時刻を保持して、コントローラ、モデル、ビュー、ヘルパー、(ownなlib配置の)ライブラリのどこからも参照できるようにするには、どうすべきでしょうか。

ぱっと思いつくのは、ApplicationControllerのフィルターでグローバル変数で管理する(あるいは管理するクラスを利用する)という方法ですが、本当にそれで良いのでしょうか。

管理するクラスで処理する場合、
グローバル変数にアクセスすべきか。
クラス変数にアクセスすべきか。
安全かわかりませんがThreadにインスタンス変数を入れて保管すべきか。
そのあたりの良し悪しがわからないので教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下はStack Overflowに投稿された質問 [How to get the time at which a request is made from the request object in rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661303)に対する[Romanの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690430)を少し改変したものです

Rack Middlewareを作成し、リクエストにタイムスタンプを付加します

app/middleware/timestamp.rb

```
class Timestamp
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env[:timestamp] = Time.now
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

config/application.rbに`config.middleware.use`を追加します

```
config.middleware.use "Timestamp"
```

これで、`request.env[:timestamp]`でタイムスタンプが取得できます

---

練習がてらgemにしてみました

```
gem 'rack-request_timestamp'
```

してbundle installでインストールした後、config/application.rbに

```
config.middleware.use Rack::RequestTimestamp
```

を追加してください。

```
request.env[:timestamp]
```

でタイムスタンプが取れます。

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

[steveklabnik/request_store](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) gemを使い、`ApplicationController`のフィルターで値を設定するとよいのではないでしょうか。

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_timestamp

  def set_timestamp
   RequestStore.store[:timestamp] = Time.now
  end
end

# コントローラ/モデル/ビュー/ヘルパーなどで
RequestStore.store[:timestamp]
```

`RequestStore`はグローバルに参照できて、スレッドセーフなどにまつわる問題の面倒を見てくれます。

### 理由

グローバル変数やクラス変数はスレッドセーフではないのでお勧めできません。

[Thread#[]](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/Thread/i/=5b=5d.html)や[Thread#[]=](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/Thread/i/=5b=5d=3d.html)を使うとスレッド固有のデータを格納することが出来ます。

`Thread.current[:foo] = :bar`のように値をいれれば、コントローラ/モデル/ビュー/ヘルパーどこからでも参照できます。

単純にリクエストごとに毎回値を設定/参照するだけなら以下のようなミドルウェアを書くといいと思います。

```
class Timestamp
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    Thread.current[:timestamp] = Time.now
    @app.call(env)
  end

  def self.current
    Thread.current[:timestamp]
  end
end

# コントローラ/モデル/ビュー/ヘルパーなどで
Timestamp.current
```

しかし、同じスレッドで何度もリクエストが処理されるような場合、スレッドに設定されたデータが残っていて問題が起こる可能性があるので、以下のようにリクエストごとに設定した値を消す処理が必要になってくると思います。

```
  def call(env)
    Thread.current[:timestamp] = Time.now
    @app.call(env)
  ensure
    Thread.current[:timestamp] = nil
  end
```

`RequestStore`を使うとそのあたりの面倒を見てくれるので楽です。

参考: [Rails - リクエスト単位でグローバルな参照を持たせてAuditログをスッキリ実装したい - Qiita](http://qiita.com/ainame/items/823b396d560d82194d48)

Answer (score 1):

apache 等のログをsed,grep,awkといったunixコマンドを使って取得することで、
rubyやrailsの仕掛けに苦闘する理由を根本的に消す方法もあり得ると思います。

色々状況はあり得るのですが、説明のために一番簡単な状況を仮定しますと、
例えばwebサーバーがapacheで、railsアプリしか扱わず、
その状態でホントに最後のリクエストログから時刻をとるには
以下のようなコマンド展開を利用したやり方が使えます。

```
log = `tail -n 1 /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log | awk '{print substr($4,2)}'`.chop
#=> "13/Oct/2015:10:04:53"
```